# Shorten url and share in react native

Tags: react-native, share

I want to share a url like an anchor tag ( for example it should display  click here and on clicking it should take us to a url) across apps(whatsapp, fb, insta etc)in react native. Currently I am using react-native-share library. Is there any way to achieve it.

Comment: React Native has it's own Share, you shouldn't even need to use an external library.

Answer (score 1):

react-native provides a way for your app to open url's (which may trigger the opening of an app via deep-links like: whatsapp://url):

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

Check [source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html).